# Find limits for scale_x or y continous or avoid to remove rows in ggplot2 and ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

i also have tried `scale_x_continous(limit=c(0,150))` and `scale_y_continnous(limit=c(0,150))` `+geom_smooth(method='lm')` but not getting  the points code is

```
register_google(key=api)
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(104.,1.35), zoom = 10)
ggmap(map)+geom_point(data=cordinate,aes(x=X,y=Y))+
  geom_text_repel(data=cordinate,aes(x=X,y=Y,label=NPCs),fontface='bold')+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,150))+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

mentioned limits are not working its only showing the map but not showing the points i also
reviewed previous question on this platform but could not find working material
so google map api is working fine as its showing map but not points.
error i am getting is:

Warning messages:

1: Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

2: Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_text_repel).

Comment: If you remove the `limits` of the `scale_y` and `scale_x` the points appear where expected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: then its only again showing the map but not points on map

Comment: Try to use `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,150), ylim = c(0,150))` and remove the limits of the `scale_x` and `scale_y`

Comment: but again question is which value should i given in ```coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,150), ylim = c(0,150))```

Comment: can you contect me on my email ```talha.zafar.j@gmail.com``` i need help to solve it urgently

Comment: ```coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,150), ylim = c(0,150))```  still not working

Comment: OP, we cannot help much here, since we do not have enough information to see the problem.  If you use `coord_cartesian(xlim=..., ylim=...)`, make sure to remove *both* `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()` terms.  If you're looking for the numbers... they are usually based on `min()` and `max()` of the data in your plot (X and Y), with a bit of margin put in place (the term `expand=` in the `scale_x_` and `scale_y_` terms).

Comment: One more thing - try to plot just the data in `cordinate` with `geom_point(...)` and `geom_text_repel(...)`.  Do you still have points removed?  What are the `X` and `Y` values, and do they make sense when you just plot the map?

Comment: i find the solution as data values was out of range as given data was not organized so after organizing the data its working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given values in the dateset was out of range and i changed the values by
`x=y`
`y=x`

```
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(104.,1.35), zoom = 10)

ggmap(map)+geom_point(data=cordinate,aes(x=Y,y=X))
    +geom_text_repel(data=cordinate,aes(x=Y,y=X,label=NPCs),fontface='bold')
    +scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150))
    +scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,150))+geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

that solved my problem as data was not going out of range after applying this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).